# How can I get usernames to tab complete again in 19.04 server when using su?

Tags: server, bash, auto-completion

One of my servers was originally running Ubuntu Server 18.04 (Bionic) and a very common task would be to substitute user, eg. `su` like this:

```
su someusername
```

Usually I would use tab completion to avoid typing the entire username. However, after upgrading to Ubuntu Server 19.04 this no longer auto completes when pressing tab. When I press tab right after typing `su` I get a list of files instead of usernames.

I have verified that I have `bash-completion` installed and I even tried:

```
source /etc/bash_completion
```

However, it didn't help.

Comment: I don't know how to restore the original behavior, but just wanted to note that it seems to be part of a greater change that replaces the implementation of `su` provided by the `login` (`shadow`) package with one from `util-linux` - the latter provides its own completions file whereas the former apparently used a deprecated `_su` provided by the `bash-completions` package. For background, see [util-linux: Please use login/passwd implementations provided by util-linux](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=833256)

Comment: ... note that it apparently **will** complete usernames if you use one of the explicit options `su -u`, `su --user` or `su - ` (to start a login shell for the target user)